# Are verified certificates more convincing to employers than "unverified" ones? (Coursera)

Tags: interviewing, career-development

Amongst the employers who pay attention to Coursera certifications, are [verified certificates](http://help.coursera.org/customer/portal/articles/1167998-what-is-a-verified-certificate-how-can-i-use-it-) more convincing to employers than "unverified" ones?

I am aware of [What is the value of a Coursera certificate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21526/452) and [Are verifiable MOOC program's of study recognised by employers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/32822/9218), but neither of them address the usefulness of the verification.

I'd be especially interested in interviewer surveys.

Comment: Personally I am unimpressed by any certifications. They are the least useful of all qualifications on a resume.

Comment: Certificates are like diplomas, they don't tell me what you can do.  I've worked with a person with no college degree who was better than some Ivy Leaguers.  You are what matters, not the paper (or virtual certificate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will always be

> it depends

Put them on the resume, but if the course was project based, then upload those projects to the web, and mention them as well.

If you took programming courses, you can get a free public account on github.  Upload your projects there, and mention that on your resume.  I've gotten several "out of the blue" interviews due to my github account.

The github account will backup the certificate with proof that you can actually code, which already puts you ahead of the game, according to [coding horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/).

Comment: beware that a lot of certification systems don't allow you to give others access to the code (or whatever) you wrote for the assignments. They're under a similar NDA as you'd have to sign with any halfway competent company as a term of your employment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the certificate, role, interviewer and you.

A verified one is better than an unverified one, but either may be worthless or a deal-clincher, with the difference of verified or not being mostly irrelevant.

As a rule, consider them all as supplementary 'bonus' material, to distinguish you from another candidate and be a topic of conversation at interview, rather than a core part of your application.